# Problema al intercambiar valores

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `textarea` en el cual, al dar click al botón, lee cuántas líneas tiene.

Una vez leídas se meten en un `Array` y puedo sacar un length. Comienzo una nueva función donde voy a intentar mezclar las líneas, cambiándolas de lugar unas con otras y poder verlo en tiempo real.

Inicié un intervalo para hacerlo cada segundo. El intervalo funciona bien, el problema es cambiar de lugar las líneas.

Pd: no tiene botón de parada aún, pero se hará, no hace falta añadirlo, se hacerlo.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let btn = getBtn();

    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        getElements();
    });
})
function getBtn(){
    return document.querySelector('.random');
}

function getElements(){
    //obtenemos el valor del textarea
    let txt = document.querySelector('.txt').value;
    //obtenemos el número de líneas como array
    let spl = txt.split('\n');

    //comenzamos a randomizar
    startRandom(txt, spl);
}

function startRandom(txt, spl){
    //declaramos un intervalo
    let itv = 1000;

    //declaramos dos rng con max

    //iniciamos el intervalo
    setInterval(function(){
        let rng = randomSplValue(spl);
        let rpg = randomSplValue(spl);
        console.log(spl[rng]);
        console.log(spl[rpg]);
        let aux = spl[rng];
        spl[rng] = spl[rpg];
        spl[rng] = aux;
    },500);
    
}

function randomSplValue(spl){
    //Obtener número random con maximo del lng
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(spl.length));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>017</title>
    <script src="js/017.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/017.css">
</head>
<body>
<textarea class="txt"></textarea>
<br>
<button class="random">RANDOMIZE</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por cierto debo comentarte que en la lógica que aplicas hay un margen de error y es que de ninguna manera estas sorteando, filtrando o controlando la posibilidad de una colisión de los números que generaste de manera aleatoria, la posibilidad de que esto suceda es mínima, pero incrementa aun mas cuando lo redondeas. Así que puede que exista la posibilidad de que sobrescribas un valor sin darte cuenta, checa eso, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, lo pensé y se me olvidó haciendo cosas, ya tengo algo mas que hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una manera mas sencilla de hacer esto es utilizando el método sort, para tener mas control también puedes usar el método map para convertir cada valor en un objeto que contenga un numero aleatorio el cual puedas sortear, mira el siguiente ejemplo

```js
let arr = ['Hola', 'b', 'u', 'r', 1, 2, 3, {perros: true}]

let random = arr
  .map((a) => ({sort: Math.random(), value: a}))
  .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
  .map((a) => a.value)

console.log(random)
```

Aquí lo que pasa es que mapeamos los valores en un objeto y le asignamos un valor random con `Math.random()` en la key sort y mantenemos el valor original del valor en otra llave en el primer map, luego utilizamos sort para sortear los objetos descendentemente por el numero random anterior y lo mapeamos de vuelta para devolver cada valor a la raíz del array.

Esto lo podrías implementar con tu código de la siguiente manera (de una manera muy resumida):

```js
const start = document.querySelector('#start')
const txt = document.querySelector('#txt');

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let arr = txt.value.split('\n')
  let inter = setInterval(() => {
    let random = arr
    .map((a) => ({sort: Math.random(), value: a}))
    .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
    .map((a) => a.value)
    txt.value = random.join('\n')
  }, 1000)
  let clear = setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(inter)
  }, 10000)
})
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">
hola
como estas
que
me cuentas
</textarea>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: La sintaxis del map me parece algo liosa aun, estoy comenzando a programar. Pero la verdad, viendo como funciona, creo que es bastante mejor de como me salió a mi. Si hubiera una forma de ver en ms cuál tarda menos...

Comment: Nice bro, realmente la manera mas eficiente y resumida seria con map y sort, y son metodos faciles de usar luego que los entiendes, tu forma es muy verbosa y funcional, luego te darás cuenta que siempre la manera mas entendible de hacer las cosas es de manera compacta y no tan explicita. Otra cosa es que aunque relativamente map y sort son mas eficiente ya que es low level, en cuestiones de tiempo no hace mucha diferencia, mi intervlao es lento para que notes que funciona pero esto es intencional, saludos :D

Comment: Hombre, con un intervalo de 10 ms hubiera visto tambien el cambio eh XD. Barajar palabras entre líneas se ve muy fácilmente XD.
Es mas, por probar acabo de hacerlo a 1ms y se ve igual de bien XD

Comment: JAJA nice! So, un saluido.

Comment: Me quede pegado en la pregunta y quería ver como lo podía hacer con vue jajaja por si a alguien le interesa https://jsfiddle.net/denyncrawford/dknoyfgv Incluso añadí un botón para parar.

Answer (score 1):

Ya di con la solución, el problema es que no me acordé de hacer un parseInt al número generado aleatoriamente, por tanto, me devolvía un valor de texto en vez de numerico, e intentaba trabajar con el:

```
function randomSplValue(spl){
    //Obtener número random con maximo del lng
    var rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(spl.length));
    return parseInt(rng);
}
```

Cambié esa función y resuelto

Comment: Que bueno que haya encontrado la solución

Comment: ¿Por qué `parseInt()` es la solución, si [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) devuelve un entero?

Comment: @Triby no había notado eso jaja

Comment: Pues me devolvía un valor de texto, vete tu a saber por qué, pero me di cuenta con un console.log XD
Le puse el parseInt y comenzó a funcionar como quería

Comment: Si estabas obteniendo una cadena en lugar de entero, no era dentro de esa función, innecesaria, por cierto. De cualquier forma, la solución propuesta por @DєηyηCrawford es más efectiva, sencilla y no permite duplicados.